# Оптимизация SQL запроса с подзапросами

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет. Нужна помощь в оптимизации запроса. Есть таблица с товарами, которые приходят и уходят с склада. Нужно оптимизировать 4 поля которые делают расчёты с этими товарами. Получается такая ситуация, что при каждом запросе происходит "пролопачивание" всей базы по нескольку раз (т.к. поля с подзапросами). На вход этой функции приходит две даты и в этом промежутке делаются расчёты.
В идеале хотелось бы сделать выборку данных, а после чего производить расчёт с полученными данными, как это сделать не пойму.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetItemsForPeriodFunc]
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @startDate DATE,
    @endDate Date
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS

RETURN 
(

    SELECT DISTINCT item.Name, item.Code, 

    --расчет пришедшего товара 
    ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ItemCount) FROM InOutWarehouse AS IOW
    WHERE IOW.ItemID = InOutWarehouse.ItemID AND DateCreated >= @startDate AND 
    DateCreated <= @endDate AND IOW.InOut = 1),0) AS CountIN,

    --расчет ушедшего товара
    ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ItemCount) FROM InOutWarehouse AS IOW
    WHERE IOW.ItemID = InOutWarehouse.ItemID AND DateCreated >= @startDate AND 
    DateCreated <= @endDate AND IOW.InOut = 0),0) AS CountOut,

    --расчет остатка с предыдущего периода
    ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ItemCount) FROM InOutWarehouse AS IOW
    WHERE IOW.ItemID = InOutWarehouse.ItemID AND DateCreated >=  DATEADD(month, -1, @startDate)  AND 
    DateCreated <= @startDate AND IOW.InOut = 1),0)- ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ItemCount) FROM InOutWarehouse AS IOW
    WHERE IOW.ItemID = InOutWarehouse.ItemID AND DateCreated >=  DATEADD(month, -1, @startDate)  AND 
    DateCreated <= @startDate AND IOW.InOut = 0),0) AS LLP,

    --расчет наличия товара
    ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ItemCount) FROM InOutWarehouse AS IOW
    WHERE IOW.ItemID = InOutWarehouse.ItemID AND DateCreated >=  DATEADD(month, -1, @startDate)  AND 
    DateCreated <= @startDate AND IOW.InOut = 1),0)-ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ItemCount) FROM InOutWarehouse AS IOW
    WHERE IOW.ItemID = InOutWarehouse.ItemID AND DateCreated >=  DATEADD(month, -1, @startDate)  AND 
    DateCreated <= @startDate AND IOW.InOut = 0),0) +
    ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ItemCount) FROM InOutWarehouse AS IOW
    WHERE IOW.ItemID = InOutWarehouse.ItemID AND DateCreated >= @startDate AND 
    DateCreated <= @endDate AND IOW.InOut = 1),0)-ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ItemCount) FROM InOutWarehouse AS IOW
    WHERE IOW.ItemID = InOutWarehouse.ItemID AND DateCreated >= @startDate AND 
    DateCreated <= @endDate AND IOW.InOut = 0),0) AS NLP 


    FROM InOutWarehouse INNER JOIN Item item ON InOutWarehouse.ItemID = item.ID
    WHERE DateCreated >= @startDate AND DateCreated <= @endDate
)
```

Comment: Начните с упрощения полей вроде LLP, разница из двух запросов конечно не нужна, там одного `sum(case when IOW.InOut = 0 then -ItemCount else ItemCount end)` достаточно. после этого уже можно смотреть запрос дальше... А вообще поле InOut в БД стоило делать не 1/0 а 1/-1 что бы можно было количество просто умножать на него в запросах

Comment: У меня вообще мысль была, сделать запрос на выборку и из этих данных идти.. тем самым все 4 вычесляемых полей должны уйти с отдельным запросом к базе. Ну если не 4 то 3 точно. Попробовать сейчас возможности нет, но а если с переменными?

Comment: Да, их потом надо по возможности свести к одному запросу с правильной группировкой и очень может быть, что это возможно. но тратить два часа на вычитывание этой простыни и представления структуры БД на основе запроса нет никакого настроения. так что я предлагаю двигаться по частям, сначала сократить то что явно сокращается, более короткую простыню будет легче понимать, особенно если текст нормально отформатировать

Comment: Ладно, буду завтра пробовать. А вообще хотелось бы какой-то пример, есть у кого? Отталкиваться проще было бы, так в этой теме я слабоват

Comment: @murattick сообщите вашу версию SQL Server - это нужно для понимания какие оконные функции поддерживает  ваша версия сервера. Предоставьте структуру таблиц, используемых в запросе.

Comment: @SergeNazarenko Добрый день. SQL Server 2008. В данном случае используется всего 2 таблицы. Item - ItemID, Name и таблица прихода\ухода товара с\на скад. Выборка идёт именно из таблицы прихода и ухода товаров. На вход получает 2 даты и должно производится вычисление сколько товаров пришло, сколько осталось, сколько осталось за предыдущий пероид и всколько осталось на конец периода. Структура таблицы по которой происходит выборка состоит из - ItemID int, ItemCount int, InOut bit, DateCreated date

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (ItemID int, ItemCount int, InOut bit, DateCreated date)
INSERT INTO @t1 SELECT ItemID, ItemCount, InOut, DateCreated
```

`FROM InOutWarehouse INNER JOIN Item AS item ON InOutWarehouse.ItemID = item.ID WHERE DateCreated <= @endDate`

```
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT item.Name, item.Code,

--расчет пришедшего товара 
ISNULL(( SELECT SUM(ItemCount) FROM @t1 AS IOW
WHERE IOW.ItemID = item.ID AND DateCreated BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
GROUP BY InOut
HAVING InOut = 1),0) AS 'Пришло',

--расчет ушедшего товара
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ItemCount) FROM @t1 AS IOW
WHERE IOW.ItemID = item.ID AND DateCreated BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
GROUP BY InOut
HAVING InOut = 0),0) AS 'Отправленно',

--расчет остатка с предыдущего периода
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ItemCount) FROM @t1 AS IOW
WHERE IOW.ItemID = item.ID AND DateCreated < @startDate 
GROUP BY InOut
HAVING InOut = 1),0)
-ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ItemCount) FROM @t1 AS IOW 
WHERE IOW.ItemID = item.ID AND DateCreated < @startDate 
GROUP BY InOut
HAVING InOut = 0),0) AS 'Остаток с предыдущего периода',

--расчет наличия товара
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ItemCount) FROM @t1 AS IOW
WHERE IOW.ItemID = item.ID AND IOW.InOut = 1 AND IOW.DateCreated <= @endDate),0)
-ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ItemCount) FROM @t1 AS IOW
WHERE IOW.ItemID = item.ID AND IOW.InOut = 0 AND IOW.DateCreated <= @endDate),0) AS 'Наличие товара'

FROM @t1 AS tbl INNER JOIN Item AS item ON tbl.ItemID = item.ID 
Where DateCreated BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
GROUP BY item.ID, item.Name, item.Code, ItemID
ORDER BY item.Name

END
```

Пока что придумал только вот так, с временном таблицей.
Может есть у кого еще соображения как его можно упростить?

> Начните с упрощения полей вроде LLP, разница из двух запросов конечно не нужна, там одного sum(case when IOW.InOut = 0 then -ItemCount else ItemCount end) достаточно.

С данным примером расчёт идёт не верный.